# Is this a suitable topological quantum field theory?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, topological-field-theory

I thought the last days on how to construct topological quantum field theories (TQFTs) and now I have the following idea:
Suppose I have a 4-dimensional manifold $M$ with a 2-form bosonic field $B$ (just an antisymmetric tensor) and a 4-form propagator field $\Pi$. This 4-form field has something special: It takes values on two different points of $M$, more precisely, if $x,y \in M$ then
$\Pi = \Pi_{\alpha \beta \mu \nu}(x,y)dx^\alpha \wedge dx^\beta \wedge dy^\mu \wedge dy^\nu $.
In other words, this non-local forms takes two elements $dx$ from the cotangent bundle on $x$ and two elements $dy$ from the cotangent bundle on $y$. Now I define my action:
\begin{equation}
S =\int_M B \wedge B + \int_M \int_M B \wedge \Pi \wedge B + \int_M \int_M \Pi \wedge \Pi.
\end{equation}
Note that double integrals mean that two different spacetime integrations are performed, effectively I have an 8-form field. It is independent on metric. But does it make sense for a TQFT? I think about some homotopy-related things.

Comment: I think the question is a potentially nice question, but before asking if it's a TQFT you should ask more things. Like, 1. does it even have dynamics? It seems not, unless you hide derivatives inside $\Pi$. 2. Why not ask the same question for $B$ a one-form and $\Pi$ a, let's call it, $(1|1)$-form? The most interesting term is $B\wedge \Pi\wedge B$ anyways. (1/2)

Comment: (2/2) 3. Since $\Pi$ takes values in $\bigwedge^\bullet\mathrm{T}_x M\otimes\bigwedge^\bullet\mathrm{T}_y M$ why does it have to be antisymmetric wrt to $\mathrm{d}x$'s and $\mathrm{d}y$'s? If the name "propagator field" actually comes from propagators of higher-form fields, these are symmetric upon exchanging $x$ and $y$, i.e. $Π_{αβμν} = Π_{μναβ}$. 4. How would you path-integrate over $Π$'s? some metric dependence can come in from the measure.